# Unpermitted parameters issue Ruby on Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncontroller

I'm currently trying to understand how permitted parameters works in ruby.

Usually, in my_model.rb I have:

```
has_many: some_other_model 
*
*
*
def my_model_params
  params.require(:my_model).permit( :column1, some_other_model_attributes %i[other_column1])
  etc...
```

and in the update function

```
my_object.update_attributes(my_model_params)
```

with a well formatted json which has some my_model root, and some_other_model_attributes as a child (array) with values.

My problem is I receive a json like this one

[image]

However the different arrays inside (such as **codification**, **general_information**) do contain attributes of the mission (general_information contains **reference** that is a column in the mission table) but there isn't any column named codification, or relation to a codification_attributes.

So, when I add :
`general_information: %i[reference]` in the permitted params, it says `unknown attribute 'general_information' for Mission`.

If not, no error are raised but in the log I can see `unpermitted_parameter:  general_information`. And my object is not updated.

Finally if I reject it, there is no more `unpermitted_parameter:  general_information` in the log but my object is not updated either.

I tried to set `config.action_controller.action_on_unpermitted_parameters` to false in my development config, it did nothing and it's probably a bad idea for production environment anyway.

The use of `.permit!` (even if it works) is currently not an option. And even though I think the json needs to be re-formatted it'd be better to find an other solution.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Maybe this is what you're looking for? https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Answer (score 0):

`unpermitted_parameter: ...` in logs in not a problem which you need to fix, it's just an info.

How it works - you just permit needed parameters, you may think about them as a hash. Unpermitted parameters will not go into the model even if they are present in params. It means when you call

```
my_object.update_attributes(my_model_params)
```

it works like

```
my_object.update_attributes(column1: value_for_column1_from_params)
```

Keys in params should be named exactly as columns in the model, otherwise you need to prepare params somehow before create/update